# Is there any way to get intellisense for python dicts?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently started using python. I am learning pygame. Today I noticed that when I create a dict its not giving me proper intellisense for keys of dicts.

```
d = {"some_key": :"value"}
```

When I put the cursor like below and press CTRL + Space for suggestions it doesn't show `"some_key"` in the list. Sometimes it shows values too `some_key` and `value`

```
d["|"]  (| pointing curcsor)
```

Is there any extension I need to install or any setting I need to change to enable intellisense or this feature is not present in vscode for python?

Comment: I am not sure about intellisense specifically, but python dictionaries are dynamic structures whose key set can change at any time, so it can't really give you suggestions.  They can be used as static tables, but they're intended for run time use.  Can you use a python class, which should give you proper completion?

Comment: @Max Well I can use class but its not needed in my code.

Comment: I don't think I've seen this feature in any editors. In general @Max's point is well received, but a lot of intellisense-like features are "best effort", especially since objects are dynamic regardless in Python. Seems to me if you have a dict that is explicitly instantiated with certain keys, those specific keys at least could be provided statically. It's an interesting idea.

As an aside, it might be better to use named variables/constants in this situation if you're worried about mistyping keys and so-on.

Comment: for this the code has to be executed and VSC does not do that